# Refactoring multiple mysql queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, erd

I am currently developing a system which generates various reports for a client and i need pointing in the direction in-order to achieve what i need.

The current situation is that i need to produce an overview of tasks which are outstanding (and some details about what is remaining).

So far i have created a list of all tasks so far (including information about the customer), this was achieved in the following query:

```
SELECT `fusion_repairs`.*, `fusion_customers`.*
FROM `fusion_repairs` 
RIGHT JOIN `fusion_customers` 
ON `fusion_repairs`.`customer_id` = `fusion_customers`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY `fusion_repairs`.`repair_id`                                                        
DESC LIMIT 20
```

Ideally i need to be able to check to see if the customer has been emailed about the task (`fusion_mail` table). If there are no mail records found for this task then i still want to show it (so another right join is out of the question.

I also need to do the same with the `fusion_response` table to check to see if the customer has sent in a response. If they haven't then i still want to display the task anyway.

Obviously i know i can achieve this by running a query within the main select query, but this doesn't sit well in my head. Is there a way i can do this in 1 query instead?

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query structure to use left joins only - essentially the same as a right join but then not having to swap between left and right join.

The fact you right-joined customers onto repairs tells me customers is the main table so now we can say get me everything from customers, join in repairs if a record exists.

```
SELECT `fusion_repairs`.*, `fusion_customers`.*
FROM   `fusion_customers` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `fusion_repairs` ON `fusion_repairs`.`customer_id` = `fusion_customers`.`customer_id`
ORDER BY `fusion_repairs`.`repair_id`                                                        
DESC LIMIT 20
```

Here we can use left outer join to see if we have any mail, if not, do not remove the row and the same with response

```
SELECT `fusion_repairs`.*, `fusion_customers`.*
FROM   `fusion_customers` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `fusion_repairs` ON `fusion_repairs`.`customer_id` = `fusion_customers`.`customer_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `fusion_mail` ON `fusion_mail`.`repair_id` = `fusion_repairs`.`repair_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `fusion_response` ON `fusion_response`.`repair_id` = `fusion_repairs`.`repair_id`
ORDER BY `fusion_repairs`.`repair_id`                                                        
DESC LIMIT 20
```

Now my question is.. What do you want to be returned? If there are 5 mail records then there will be 5 records for the 1 repair record. Do you just want a yes/no tick just to say they have then maybe a correlated subquery in the main select is actually what you want or a group by and count the number of mail inside a case to tick.

Let me know what you want as your output to finish the query up.

EDIT:

I've made an update to the query to take into account the information you gave me. Please note I have no idea how you want to output the final result so I just made a guess! Let me know if this solves it otherwise back to the drawing board for me!

```
SELECT  fusion_repairs.*, 
        fusion_customers.*, 
        CONCAT( CASE WHEN fusionMail.mail_type_A > 0 THEN 'displayA' ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN fusionMail.mail_type_B > 0 THEN 'displayB' ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN fusionMail.mail_type_C > 0 THEN 'displayC' ELSE '' END) as email_font_awesome_icon,
        CONCAT( CASE WHEN fusionResponse.response_status_A > 0 THEN 'displayA' ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN fusionResponse.response_status_B > 0 THEN 'displayB' ELSE '' END,
                CASE WHEN fusionResponse.response_status_C > 0 THEN 'displayC' ELSE '' END) as response_font_awesome_icon
FROM    fusion_customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN fusion_repairs ON fusion_repairs.customer_id = fusion_customers.customer_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  repair_id,
            SUM(CASE WHEN mail_type = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS mail_type_A,
            SUM(CASE WHEN mail_type = 2 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS mail_type_B,
            SUM(CASE WHEN mail_type = 3 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS mail_type_C
    FROM fusion_mail
    GROUP BY repair_id
) fusionMail ON fusionMail.repair_id = fusion_repairs.repair_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  repair_id,
            SUM(CASE WHEN response_status = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS response_status_A,
            SUM(CASE WHEN response_status = 2 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS response_status_B,
            SUM(CASE WHEN response_status = 3 THEN 1 else 0 END) AS response_status_C
    FROM fusion_response
    GROUP BY repair_id
) fusionResponse ON fusionResponse.repair_id = fusion_repairs.repair_id
```

Comment: Basically within the mail table there is a mail type which will either be (contact, reminder or return). I would just like to display a font awesome icon for each one.

Comment: @LewisBrowne are you expecting only 1 email per repair or multiple? Do you mind having multiple rows per email so 1 repair can have multiple rows? Are you wanting 1 column per type with a tick/cross if it's that type? Need a bit more details! (this is not even including the responses yet!)

Comment: Basically each repair can have an unlimited amount of emails, however i want to know if a repair has en email with an `email_type` of either (contact, reminder or return). If a repair has all 3 then i will render 3 mail icons, if 2 emails then it will render 2 and if it only has 1 then it will only render 1

Comment: Will also be exactly the same for responses.

Comment: @LewisBrowne Updated query, let me know if that works for you

Comment: This is pretty much bang on what i needed, Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate how much you have just done for me.